# Changing default mount point of external HDD

Tags: 12.10, mount, mountpoint

I know hot to assign a mount point to my usb hdd(ntfs) in terminal but as soon as it's unmounted and mounted again, it goes back to default folder that is `/media/Seagate Expansion Drive`

What i did so far:

> sudo mkdir /media/myusb

then mounted

> sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/myusb

So how to assign `myusb` folder as default mount point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been answered in the [Ubuntu Help (Rename USB Drive)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RenameUSBDrive):

> sudo ntfslabel /dev/sdb1 my_new_label

Comment: Thanks. This page led me to [fstab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) page, edited `/etc/fstab` and voila!